# Why does my phone think it's low on space?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

Before downloading a 1.14GB app on my Samsung Galaxy Phone, I had 1.24GB free in my internal storage. Strangely, I wasn't able to download the app and I got a message saying "Low on space. Phone storage space is getting low."

I don't understand why I only have 189MB left of internal storage on my phone when I didn't even manage to download the app. I already use Cache and Memory Cleaner and a task killer and I restarted my phone. I've tired looking through my internal storage folders on my PC, but I don't see anything that I can delete. What's happening here? Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the suggestions in the [insufficient-memory tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)?